# Cartoon in which a train conductor and a boy travel together to save a princess

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember the princess being kidnapped by an evil witch or queen who didn't like to smile. The boy and conductor went on a journey on the conductor's train to find out where she is and rescue her. Eventually they find her, I think and they managed to convince the evil queen or witch that smiling was good and she laughs.

Comment: Can you remember when you watched this and anything else that happens? If so you can [edit] that into your question.

Comment: Sounds like "Jim Knopf". In what language did you watch this? Could not find an english wiki entry because this is a german/french series, not sure if this was synchronized to english... But without further information i can not say for sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds extremely close the german classic book [Jim Button and Luke the Engine driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Button_and_Luke_the_Engine_Driver) which was adapted into a cartoon series in 1998 (pictures [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jim%20Knopf%20cartoon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)). It is about the boy Jim Button who grows up on a small island without knowing his real parents with the engine driver Luke being his best friend. They embark from their island on board of their train engine (turned into a boat by emptying the tank) to relieve concerns of overpopulation and come across a china-inspired country called Mandala where Princess Li Si was kidnapped by a (very witch-like) Dragon named Ms. Grindtooth who intends to use children to learn to laugh from them. In the end they do manage to defeat her which triggers a transformation into a "Golden Dragon of Wisdom" making her benevolent.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!